# Default Shell for Samba Machine Accounts

Tags: windows, samba, password

Using Samba, as a domain controller, I need to add Windows machines as users (in `/etc/passwd`), and to the Samba database as a machine. In the `/etc/passwd` file, I noticed about half the machines have a shell of `/bin/sh`, the other half have `/bin/false`.

I would prefer them all to be `/bin/false`, but only if that's acceptable, and the recommended way. **Is there any security or functional restrictions to the machine account having `/bin/false` instead of `/bin/sh`?** Currently, we are using Samba 3 on Debian Wheezy.

An example set of entries below:

```
cla-teach-54$:x:1367:1386::/home/cla-teach-54$:/bin/sh
cla-teach-55$:x:1369:1388::/home/cla-teach-55$:/bin/sh
cla-teach-56$:x:1562:1583::/home/cla-teach-56$:/bin/sh
cla-teach-57$:x:1846:1864::/home/cla-teach-57$:/bin/false
cla-teach-58$:x:1948:1960::/home/cla-teach-58$:/bin/false
cla-teach-59$:x:1949:1961::/home/cla-teach-59$:/bin/false
```

*(note: none of the home folders exist)*

Comment: Related: [Does /usr/sbin/nologin as a login shell serve a security purpose?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155139/does-usr-sbin-nologin-as-a-login-shell-serve-a-security-purpose/155140#155140)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not only acceptable, but also preferable to have them have `/bin/false` as a login shell, else someone could actually long onto the system and get shell access.

Remember to pass `-s /bin/false` to useradd to set the login shell to `/bin/false`