# login with apache user

Tags: sudo, users, webserver, su

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.portent.com/blog/design-dev/github-auto-deploy-setup-guide.htm) step by step,for

> Here we clone the repo into a chmodded /var/www/[site_dir] folder.
>   Note that we switch to the www-data user before running the git clone
>   command. This is an important step because the deploy key we generated
>   is owned by the www-data user and it will only work for that user,
>   even if you are on the root.

I need to switch to `www-data` user, but when I try `sudo su - www-data` ( or `sudo su www-data` ) I faced with **This account is currently not available.**

I try `ps aux` and I see that the *www-data* user exists, Now I want to know how can I achieve that ? ( login with www-data user)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `www-data` user is evidently configured with `/sbin/nologin` (or equivalent) as its shell, and thus the system will not allow you to login to that account. `sudo` lets you run a command as any user on the system, not just root.  To clone the repo, you just need to `sudo -u www-data git clone ...` If you really need shell access as that user, `sudo -u www-data bash` will get you there.

Of course, this all depends on suitable settings in your `sudoers` file.

Comment: yes,I found the solution https://geekpeek.net/this-account-is-currently-not-available-login-problems/

Comment: @YusefMohamadi - Adding shell access for a service user is risky. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155139/does-usr-sbin-nologin-as-a-login-shell-serve-a-security-purpose