# Can I create a No-Login-Account

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

**Hello Professionals**,

can I create a No-Login-Account, which neither **su** nor **Login** should be possible on this account?

What I've tried:

First Method:

Creating without home directory:

```
usseradd -M Test
```

```
usermod -L Test
```

Second Method:

And according to documentations,

```
useradd -r Test
```

when i use the **su** command to login, it is still able to log in.

**thanks for your help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
usermod --shell /sbin/nologin Test
```

P.S. Linux user accounts names are normally lowcase and can only contain `a-Z 0-9` and a dot (`.` - except the first or last symbol)

Comment: thanks a lot. may I ask, what for do we need such accounts? I am just trying scripting form one online exercises, therefore I am not well known with Linux OS

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155139/does-usr-sbin-nologin-as-a-login-shell-serve-a-security-purpose